# Maximizing profit in doing the jobs

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

We are given two arrays `M` (money) and `E` (experience) of integers each of size 50 at most. After Bob does the job i, two things happen:

(Let `TE` be Bob's total experience initialized by `0`)

1. Bob's experience (i.e. `TE`) is incremented by `E[i]`
2. Then, he will receive money equal to `TE*M[i]`

What is the maximum profit Bob can make if he does the jobs in the best possible order?

```
For any i we know:
1 <= E[i] <= 10^5
1 <= M[i] <= 10    

Example:
M[] = { 20, 30,  100 }
E[] = {  1,  1, 6 }

Answer: 880 = job 3-1-2 = 6*100 + 7*20 + 8*30 = 980
```

Comment: How long is the array at maximum?

Comment: shole, I have stated this array is 50 at most.

Comment: MrSmith42, sorry for misunderstanding. But this question is way more than a homework. You will realize that once you start thinking about it. I am pretty sure the only approach working on this is dynamic programming. And in dynamic programming there is no "stuck" point. You either know the recursion step or you don't.

Comment: MrSmith42, this is a simplified version of a TopCoder problem SRM691-Div1 - Level 2. And the tag for this problem is dynamic programming. So, that's all I know. And no tutorial exists for this. (Believe me Div1 - Level 2 problems are no where near homeworks ...)

Comment: I do not get the limiting factor. Whatever Bob does his money increases and his experience increases.

Comment: Why your example is not job 1-->2-->3 = 6*100 + 7*20 + 8*30 = 980?

Comment: You are right. And I changed the order of original arrays to emphasize that any order is possible.

Comment: I have a guess then: Greedy algorithm, with array sorted by Exp/Gold in descending order; If tie, then sort by Gold in ascending order.  Then the sorted array is the order of the job which yields optimal solution

Comment: What makes you think you can use DP?

Comment: You are right this simplified version can be solved greedy.

Comment: yea..the original problem's core part is at the +X exp after half of the jobs are done though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved by Greedy Algorithm (which is a special case of DP) as described follow:

1. Sort the job by ratio `Exp/Money` in descending order
2. If tie, then sort the job by `Money` in ascending order

Then the sorted job sequence is the order of the job which yields the optimal solution.

My reasoning is as follows: The ratio `Exp/Money` can be interpreted as *How much Exp can you buy with 1 money*, so it is always better if we choose the job with higher ratio first, as this increase the experience  for later jobs.

In the tie case, choose the job with smaller money reward, as this makes the job with higher money reward can be multiplied by a larger experience factor later on.

For example:

```
E = {2,1,6,1}
M = {40,20,100,10}

Sorted job = { job3, job4, job2, job1}  

= 6*100 + 7*10 + 8*20 + 10*40 = 1230
```